# Reading text file flink

Tags: apache-flink

Hi I am new with Flink I am trying to read a text file, and when I print it it appears to be unsorted.

Is that normal? Why it is not ordered? There is a way to sort it?

The original text file is:

```
01-06-2018,June,Category5,Bat,12
01-06-2108,June,Category4,Perfume,10
13-07-2018,July,Category1,Television,50
24-06-2018,June,Category4,Shirt,38
18-06-2018,June,Category5,Bat,41
01-08-2018,August,Category5,PC,32
11-06-2018,June,Category2,Laptop,39
04-06-2018,June,Category1,PC,14
26-08-2018,August,Category4,Pendrive,42
12-06-2018,June,Category2,Tablet,41
25-08-2018,August,Category1,Shirt,34
17-07-2018,July,Category5,Steamer,27
....
```

My code:
`val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val dataset = env.readTextFile("text.txt")
    dataset.print()`

And I get the lines in different order each time I execute, for example:

```
31-08-2018,August,Category2,Jewelry,38
13-08-2018,August,Category2,Mouse,35
02-07-2018,July,Category3,PC,34
04-08-2018,August,Category2,Bottle,38
04-06-2018,June,Category1,Pendrive,30
24-08-2018,August,Category1,Phone,43
11-06-2018,June,Category4,Jeans,14
28-08-2018,August,Category3,Jeans,36
14-06-2018,June,Category1,Bottle,49
....
```

Any help in order to understand this and making it ordered if possible would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the parallelism to 1, flink local mode will set the parallelism to the number of your cpu's cores, it will cause a unsorted output.